# Selenium stopping scroll early on reddit

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
comments = [] 
# instantiate height of webpage 
last_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight') 
# set target count 
itemTargetCount = 30

while itemTargetCount > len(comments): 
    # scroll to bottom of webpage
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    time.sleep(1)
    
    new_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight') 
    print(new_height)
    print(last_height)
    
    if new_height == last_height: 
        print('scroll fail')
        break 
    
    last_height = new_height 

    # select elements by ID
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "-post-rtjson-content")
    comments = [element.text for element in elements]

print(len(comments))
print(comments)
```

'''

Based on the printed text I get when I run this, it will scroll once but not a second time.
I am trying to get comments from reddit, maybe something about the html is making it not scroll further?
reddit post I'm trying to scrape:https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/13xdn8m/summer_23_promo_codes/

my output

```
    2927
    2081
    2927
    2927
    scroll fail
    19
    ['Begging like monkies for bananas but no single upvote in return... typically Reddit', 'I would like a promo code.', 'SN0XYN2VFXHEMM7C05QREA1', "I'd like a promo code if that's available.", "PM'd", 'I would like a promo code.', 'ctzzs\nPMd', "I'd like a promo code as well", 'PMd', 'Can you please send me a promo code? Thanks in advance.', "PM'd", 'Can I have a promo code?', "PM'd", 'I would love a promo code is still available.', "PM'd", 'I would love a promocode!', "PM'd", "I'll give it a try", "PM'd"]
```

Comment: Solved it, when not logged it, reddit will have a load more comments button. I will need to log in or create logic to click the button

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
comments = [] 
 
# set target count 
itemTargetCount = 30

while itemTargetCount > len(comments): 
    #Use this function to scroll down
    automate_scroll(driver)

    # select elements by ID
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.ID, "-post-rtjson-content")
    comments = [element.text for element in elements]

print(len(comments))
print(comments)
```

and add this function:

```
def automate_scroll(driver):
    # To automate the scroll up and scroll down the website
    # Define an initial value
    temp_height = 0
    while True:
        # Looping down the scroll bar
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)")
        # sleep and let the scroll bar react
        time.sleep(5)
        # Get the distance of the current scroll bar from the top
        check_height = driver.execute_script(
            "return document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;")
        # If the two are equal to the end
        if check_height == temp_height:
            break
        temp_height = check_height

    time.sleep(10)
```